# How to Pass Value to button Click Mehtod?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I Had buttons in a Listview and Had issues of it clicking multiple times on one Click, but I found a solution this one here:

This is in public override View GetView:

```
......
            view.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.btnPlayMovieButton).Click -= CheckItemClickViewNull;   
            view.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.btnPlayMovieButton).Click -= CheckItemClick; 
            view.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.btnPlayMovieButton).Click += CheckItemClick; 

....
```

And here are the Methods for that:

```
//Play Button
        public void CheckItemClickViewNull(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckItemClickGeneral(sender, e,"NULL ");

        }


        public void CheckItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckItemClickGeneral(sender, e, "NOT NULL ");

        }

        public void CheckItemClickGeneral(object sender, EventArgs e, string TypeArrivee)
        {

            Console.WriteLine ("Clicky Clicky Play Button");

            // Add Logic Here


        }
```

This Fixed the Issue of Multiple Clicks on one Click but now I have the Issue of How do i pass a value to the method to do something else

This is the Method I want to pass a value to, I need to Pass the item.seasonid
each id will be different depending on the button clicked in the listview

```
public void CheckItemClickGeneral(object sender, EventArgs e, string TypeArrivee)
        {

            Console.WriteLine ("Clicky Clicky Play Button");

            // Add Logic Here


        }
```

How would I go About doing this?

Comment: Can you explain me the requirements bit more.  I am not following your mentioned issue "Had issues of clicking multiple times"

Comment: Can you try to get the id from Sender object of button click event;
like:  
`ListView temp = (ListView)sender;`

Comment: @AneesDeen When I Scrolled the listview for some reason it added to the click event and then when i would it would go to 5 clicks if I would scroll more it would click ten